# Can't restore master/slave replication from Percona backup (slave server)

Tags: mysql, replication, percona, debian

A slave is restored from a `master` backup created with Percona xtrabackup

On the master binlog is set to expire in 14 days and this backup is less than 24 hours old

## my.cnf (master)

```
expire_logs_days   = 14
```

## restore script (slave)

```
service mysql stop

rm -r /var/lib/mysql/*

# backup is unzipped into /var/lib/mysql
xtrabackup --prepare --target-dir=/var/lib/mysql
chown -R mysql.mysql /var/lib/mysql

service mysql start

# get gtid
line=$(head -n 1 "/var/lib/mysql/xtrabackup_binlog_info")
gtid=$(echo $line | awk -F '[ ,]' '{print $3}')

mysql -u root -pPASS -e "reset master; SET GLOBAL gtid_purged='$gtid'; CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='$master_host', MASTER_USER='repl', MASTER_PASSWORD='$master_pass', MASTER_AUTO_POSITION=1; start slave"

mysql -u root -pPASS -e "show slave status\G;"
```

## Status

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State:
                  Master_Host: server.com
                  Master_User: repl
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File:
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 4
               Relay_Log_File: rep-relay-bin.000001
                Relay_Log_Pos: 4
        Relay_Master_Log_File:
             Slave_IO_Running: No
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB: mydb
          Replicate_Ignore_DB:
           Replicate_Do_Table:
       Replicate_Ignore_Table:
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error:
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 0
              Relay_Log_Space: 154
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File:
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File:
           Master_SSL_CA_Path:
              Master_SSL_Cert:
            Master_SSL_Cipher:
               Master_SSL_Key:
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 1236
                Last_IO_Error: Got fatal error 1236 from master when reading data from binary log: 'The slave is connecting using CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_AUTO_POSITION = 1, but the master has purged binary logs containing GTIDs that the slave requires. Replicate the missing transactions from elsewhere, or provision a new slave from backup. Consider increasing the master's binary log expiration period. The GTID sets and the missing purged transactions are too long to print in this message. For more information, please see the master's error log or the manual for GTID_SUBTRACT.'
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error:
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
             Master_Server_Id: 1
                  Master_UUID: fe51e8df-b7c4-11e9-be21-4061862b8d34
             Master_Info_File: /mnt/HC_Volume_8355755/mysql/master.info
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
      Slave_SQL_Running_State: Slave has read all relay log; waiting for more updates
           Master_Retry_Count: 86400
                  Master_Bind:
      Last_IO_Error_Timestamp: 210211 10:50:32
     Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp:
               Master_SSL_Crl:
           Master_SSL_Crlpath:
           Retrieved_Gtid_Set:
            Executed_Gtid_Set: 3ccc2392-45ed-11e7-bc98-4061862b8d34:1-35942477,
94bb04d3-6c4e-11eb-8631-96000080ccbb:1-2
                Auto_Position: 1
         Replicate_Rewrite_DB:
                 Channel_Name:
           Master_TLS_Version:
```

## /var/lib/mysql/xtrabackup_binlog_info

```
mysql-bin.000025    217141189   3ccc2392-45ed-11e7-bc98-4061862b8d34:1-35942477,
fe51e8df-b7c4-11e9-be21-4061862b8d34:1-25059775
```

The `gtid` value extracted from the file: `3ccc2392-45ed-11e7-bc98-4061862b8d34:1-35942477`

## update

Have also tried to fetch the second uid in `/var/lib/mysql/xtrabackup_binlog_info` by doing

```
gtid=$(tail -n 1 "$mysql_dir/xtrabackup_binlog_info")
```

Nothing works.. Same error

Comment: As the error is about `MASTER_AUTO_POSITION`, why have you set it to 1 in your script?

Comment: can you check status of "show master status " on master ?

Comment: @JYOTIRAJAI show master status returns `3ccc2392-45ed-11e7-bc98-4061862b8d34:1-35942477,
fe51e8df-b7c4-11e9-be21-4061862b8d34:1-25203198`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here
https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.3/howtos/setting_up_replication.html

I was missing the `xtrabackup --move-back` command